# Check if two files are different sizes in Bash

Tags: bash, filesize, stat

I couldn't find this question here. How do compare file sizes of two files, then do something only if the two files are of different sizes, in Bash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To complement @Steve Bennett's helpful answer:

The **`stat` options indeed vary across platforms**; it seems that the **POSIX standard doesn't mandate a `stat` *utility*** (only a library function).

Here's a **`bash` function that works on both Linux and BSD-derived OSs, including OSX**:

```
# SYNOPSIS
#   fileSize file ...
# DESCRIPTION
#   Returns the size of the specified file(s) in bytes, with each file's 
#   size on a separate output line.
fileSize() {
  local optChar='c' fmtString='%s'
  [[ $(uname) =~ Darwin|BSD ]] && { optChar='f'; fmtString='%z'; }
  stat -$optChar "$fmtString" "$@"
}
```

Sample use:

```
if (( $(fileSize FILE1.txt) != $(fileSize FILE2.txt) )); then
  echo "They're different."
fi
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately `stat` is highly unportable by not being POSIX (e.g. Solaris doesn't have it). The only portable way of determining file size is using `wc -c` which, unfortunately, might read the entire file. The `coreutils` implementation optimizes this away using `fstat()` if `[FILE]` is a regular file (`busybox` used to do this too but dropped it because it was apparently broken). Another option would be to use `find`'s `-printf` feature but this is also specific to `GNU find` (but *might* be available on a platform without `stat`). YMMV.

Answer (score 5):

Bash doesn't seem to have this as a built in, but you can use `stat`.

```
if [ $(stat -c %s FILE1.txt) -ne $(stat -c %s FILE2.txt) ]; then 
   echo "They're different."
fi
```

The exact arguments to `stat` may vary on the OS.